# Azure WebJob In its own AppService or in an AppService with Api

Tags: azure, deployment, azure-webjobs, azure-web-app-service

I have an AppService which hosts an Api. I also have two WebJobs. My question is should I host the WebJobs in the same AppService as the Api or would it be better to host each WebJob in their own AppService.

Comment: Do you mean App Service Plan (ASP)? Is there a specific reason why you would want to host your Webjobs in a different App Service  than your API app?

Answer (score 1):

> My question is should I host the WebJobs in the same AppService as the Api or would it be better to host each WebJob in their own AppService.

When you deploy WebJobs, you need to **host it in the Azure App Service** as a background task. WebJobs is a feature of Azure App Service that enables you to run a program or script in the same context as a web app, API app, or mobile app.

Also, Azure App Service payment is **determined by the App Service plan** that you run your apps on, while WebJobs is **no need for additional cost**.

For more details, you could refer to this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/webjobs-create).

Comment: I originally created a separate AppService for the Api app and each WebJob. It sounds like the downside of running the WebJob in its own AppService is the cost. Is there some specific benefit to running the WebJob in the same context as the API app (other than cost)?

Comment: @user1282345, webjob could satisfy all background processing need and do not need to interact with others. For more, you could refer to this [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46213167/azure-app-service-vs-webjob).

Answer (score 0):

WebJobs are coupled with App services or Web app in the app service plan and they run as a background task of app service. We can't have an webjob independently running without the web app on the App service plan . We can control the scaling of web job in the case of multiple instance but web job has to be run as background task of app service.

Comment: So what if the App Service isn't running?  No requests are made to it, do scheduled or continuous web jobs still run?